Meaning/usage of "much more about"
In the below contents, does much more about mean local companies are in stronger position?

We looked at consumer business and we could see that originally the view had been that you would get a lot of global scale in consumer business, and we were very strong in a number of different countries. But the reality is you don't get as much scale globally. It's much more about local scale in this kind of business.


No, the issue of scale is more local than global.

Local scale is much more relevant in this context.

'Local consumer businesses of the types under consideration perform [reasonably] well locally (possibly up to nationally) but less well than predicted internationally.' Replacing '[lack of] success' / '[not] perform well' (etc) with '[not!] get a lot of global scale' seems weaselly.

Are you asking about the phrase much more about generally or you are only interested in understanding this particular passage? If the former, the question should be elaborated it make it clear what makes the phrase itself problematic; if the latter, the question is outside the scope of this site.
